# Javascript bookmarklet for rotating images refuses to function

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've been working on a javascript bookmarklet to rotate images based off of various research. However, the finished bookmarklet doesn't properly do anything. It doesn't even throw up an error.

I've looked through it in the console, it seems that when I define a certain variable it sets it as a NaN automatically. However, even when I set that variable as a number in the console beforehand, it still ends up not functioning.

My code is as followed:

```
javascript:function img_find() {var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");return imgs;} var deg; var images = img_find(); deg = (deg + 90) % 360; for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {(function(){images[i].style = 'tranform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'})()}
```

Comment: Use an IIFE instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid code here, you are reassigning the entire style object to a string.

```js
images[i].style = 'tranform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
```

Use `let` for loop-scoping instead of wrapping the inner portion in a closure.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].style.tranform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
}
```

You should use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to run the bookmarklet.

```js
((imgs, deg, step, ms, max) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      deg = (deg + step) % 360;
      [...imgs].forEach(img => {
        img.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
      })
    }, ms * i);
  }
})(document.querySelectorAll('img'), 0, 45, 250, 100);
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
```

---

#### A minified "scriptlet" version

***Note:** I had to pass the `360` into the function as `p`, because `%36` was being escaped as `6`.*

```js
javascript:((e,d,s,t,m,p)=>{for(let i=0;i<m;i++)setTimeout(()=>{d=(d+s)%p,[...e].forEach(e=>{e.style.transform=`rotate(${d}deg)`})},t*i)})(document.querySelectorAll('img'),0,45,250,100,360);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is there one or two pieces of code that you can change to just make it spin infinitely, or at least make it not stop at upside down every time?